# How can i make my page slide on scroll Jquery or CSS (or any other way)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, smoothing

I am wondering that how I can make my page slide when user scrolls the page. I have searched for solutions all over the web but I have found nothing. One solution had so much code it wasn't even worth it.

Is there an efficient way or using a CDN that will allow me to do this?

Note: its a smooth scrolling effect that keeps sliding subtly after you scroll up or down instead of abrupt scrolling as is the default.

```
var html = $('html');
$('html').scroll(function() {
    html.animate({},500, 'swing');
});
```

But of course that doesn't make much sense.

I'm wondering if i should detect the direction of the scroll and based on that i add top:50px inside the CSS in the animate part or top:-50px if scroll direction is up.

What do you think? I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: Please show some code examples of what you have tried and did not manage to accomplish, so that people can try and help

Comment: ok updated my post. thanks

Comment: It exists a partially supported CSS `scroll-behavior` property that allow to smooth scroll upon clicking on a link internal to the page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

Comment: i am aware of this feature thank you but not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about you need a custom jQuery plugin for scrolling.
You can try http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
And there are two code examples:

1. http://manos.malihu.gr/code-example/responsive-custom-scrollbar-with-css3-media-queries/
2. http://manos.malihu.gr/add-a-custom-scrollbar-to-your-twitter-widget/

You have also option to download the project from first URL.

This is the simple example plugin and very helpful.